# System.Speech Voice Recognition not working

Tags: c#, sapi

I am using c# system.speech , and i have limited number of sentences that i wants to recognize. Here is code

```
  SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
    String[] Sentences = File.ReadAllLines(samplePath);
    Choices sentences = new Choices();
    sentences.Add(Sentences);
    GrammarBuilder gBuilder = new GrammarBuilder(sentences);
    Grammar g = new Grammar(gBuilder);
    g.Enabled = true;
    recognizer.LoadGrammar(g);

    try
    {
        recognizer.SetInputToWaveFile(filePath);
        RecognitionResult result = recognizer.Recognize();
        String ret = result.Text;
        recognizer.Dispose();
        return ret;
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException exception) { }
    return "";
```

This code throws exception when I give it some **wav** file and reason of exception is it can't find match in sample sentences. Can I force it so it must select on sentence?

Comment: Provide the code including the part where you provide the wav file to the recognizer, because for me it always work even when the sound file is complete silence (It provides confidence %) not throwing exceptions.

Comment: Also how do you initialize `recognizer`?

Comment: i have all code , i can update code , but it did not send % confidence , it seems that its not recongnizing

Comment: Edit the question and add what I've asked so I can help you by devugging here.

Comment: i can share wav file as well and sentences

Comment: Can you put the sentances?

Comment: here are two sentences
department of telecommunication engineering
university college of engineering and technology

Comment: and here is file that i want to convert
https://www.dropbox.com/s/i640yjofzdbohc5/3.wav?dl=0

Comment: Can you provide the sentences, I mean, as text?

Comment: following are sentences 
1-department of telecommunication engineering
2-university college of engineering and technology

Comment: Can you provide the file itself? maybe the format is bad.

Comment: Also, is the exception `InvalidOperationException` or `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0r8z198qhukvx4u/sample%20-%20Copy.txt?dl=0

Comment: its  NullReferenceException , cz it has null in results

Comment: Try if my answer solves it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `NullReferenceException` because the format of your **.wav** file's format is different than how `System.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine` is trying to analyse **.wav** files by default when using the `SetInputToWaveFile` method.

In order to change the read format you should use the `SetInputToAudioStream` method instead:

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("C:\\3.wav", FileMode.Open))
{
    recognizer.SetInputToAudioStream(stream, new SpeechAudioFormatInfo(5000, AudioBitsPerSample.Sixteen, AudioChannel.Stereo));
    RecognitionResult result = recognizer.Recognize();
    string ret = result.Text;
}
```

This way it reads your **.wav** file as a **stereo file**, at **16bps** and with **5000 samples per second** as your **.wav** file is really encoded.

***Note: this solved the problem for me ON YOUR FILE***

Comment: Thanks for your help but it still give same exception :(